# I am missing deadlines for coping with anxiety. What should I do?

Tags: deadlines, disability

Ever since I knew about anxiety five months ago, I started going easy with life, started to distract myself from all the stressors. I used to be very alert before deadlines previously and hence it used to interfere with my life severely. Now that I try to relax and use stress handling techniques, I feel better but I am missing deadlines. Today I got the rejection letter for a paper I submitted, which I know happened because of going easy on the deadline. Now what should I do to balance both sides?

Comment: I think the title is wrong - you are not missing deadlines "due to anxiety", but rather because you decided not to give in to your anxiety. I think that's quite different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first, and most important, step should be to find a good therapist to work with you on your anxiety if you don't already have one. *If* you already have one, talk with them about how you are feeling about this rejection. They will be in a much better position to talk you through your options than we random people on the Internet.

Keep in mind that this isn't an academic question *per se* (even though it often comes up in academic contexts), and professors and fellow students are not necessarily the best people to help you. Speaking from a little personal experience and seeing the same process in others, getting help with anxiety, burnout, and stress-related symptoms is not about finding a magic bean strategy that will allow you to put in the same hours as before, but somehow don't mind it anymore - it's about guiding you towards *acceptance* that you cannot and should not work quite as hard as you used to, along with the consequence that you may produce less output than before (but in exchange get a much better life, as you yourself said).